# System Constantly Freezes with Ryzen x1700 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, freeze, amd-processor

I ordered dedicated server with AMD Ryzen x1700, installed here Ubuntu 18.04

```
Kernel is 4.15.0-29-generic
```

There are 2x500SSD and 1x4000HDD, they are mounted and working. RAM 64GB.

**root@159:~# fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf3b7577b

Device     Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048   67110911  67108864    32G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2       67110912   68159487   1048576   512M 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       68159488 1000213167 932053680 444.4G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdc: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

**root@159:~# free**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       65985312     1111648    63810352       31760     1063312    64219256
Swap:      33554428           0    33554428
```

System freezes every day 1-3 times constantly in past week.
Nothing suspicious in syslog / dmesg. 
The last time it happens, log screen (prev time - nothing) :
http://prntscr.com/kjd2wl
Just freeze, and becomes unreachable until hard reboot.

I checked hard drives via fsck -f, its fine.

Temperatures of CPU and hard drives are fine, server without load. Dont know what to check else. I already read many topics there, but nothing same with me, all topics are old or for older versions of kernel / ubuntu.

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? What does `free` show you? Old solutions MAY still work, or at least point you at things to look at. New Ubuntu releases are NOT 100% different from old ones.

Comment: @waltinator , added info in start post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I ordered full hardware check, and hoster sent me review.

> Dear Client,
>
> Unfortunately your server crashed while the hardware check, so we
>   decided to replace the sever, but reconnect the old drives.
>
> Afterwards we checked your drives and saw that your 4 TB drive is
>   broken and doesn't start any more. So please confirm the data loss to
>   the drive.
>
> Your server is now booted into the rescue System.

I will try to work with new hardware, if problem still here, I'll let to know.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of work, server freezed again with new hard drive. Now they fixed BIOS and it works 2 days without freezes. Win?

Comment: Did it ever crash again after the "BIOS fix"?

Comment: No, never. Works almost 10 monthes without reboot already.

Comment: Do you know what exactly did they change in BIOS? Upgrade firmware? Or maybe disable C6 or C-States?

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont know.